# objective-c displaying a UIAlert on applicationWillResignActive

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, background-process

In my app can download some JSON data which gets converted to a Core Data entity and if it has a certain status a duplicate of that entity is created (we don't want them editing the original data). There's a save button so they can save their data but we also want to check before they either quit or put the app into the background if they have unsaved data and if so give them the option to save (showing a UIAlert). I've put the alert in applicationWillResignActive which seemed to be the logical place but it never appear until the app is relaunched from the background.

Is there a way to display an alert that will suspend the move to the background until the user touches a button and all relevant action is completed?

Thanks

Comment: Since the iOS environment retains all the controller and variable states as it is even in background, I don't think there is any way to hold the screen once the user has pressed the home button.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to "hold on" to your position as the active application when the user hits the **Home** button (or switches away to handle a notification, or receives a call, etc).

The iOS-appropriate way to handle this is to either: save on exit and be able to undo when the user comes back, or to store it temporarily (since you might get killed while the user is away) and then present the modified version when the user switches back and allow them to save at that time.